# How do I assign a redux action that takes an argument to an onClick attribute?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I get a warning that the first line of my render function assigns a value to column but it is never used.

The action fires but the payload holds an incorrect object.

```
import React from "react";
import { addCard } from "../../actions/card-actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Column extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const column = this.props.column;
        return (
            <AddCardLink onClick={column => {this.props.addCard(column)}}>
                Add new card...
            </AddCardLink>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addCard: column => dispatch(addCard(column))
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Column);
```

my reducer;

```
const cardReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CARD_DRAG":
      return onDragEnd(state, action.payload);
    case "CARD_ADD":
      console.log("action fired", action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        editing: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: What does the payload hold? Please show your reducer too.

Comment: payload holds a class; Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `onClick={column => this.props.addCard(column) }` you are not using the const column previously defined, you are just expecting an argument called column. 
Try this:

`onClick={ ()=> this.props.addCard(column)}`

In this way you are just using an anonymous function to wrap `addCard` so it doesn't get executed immediately after the component loads

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and works perfectly. Thanks.